# Influence of dimension of $V$ on the existence of a linear endomorphism with no eigenvalues of a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I've achieved to show that there exists a linear endomorphism with no eigenvectors of a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$, and I've also shown that such a linear endomoprhism can't exist from $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$, since its polynomial characteristic would have at least 1 eigenvalue, and thus there would be the corresponding eigenvector. But now I'm wondering if the dimension of $V$ does influence those results? Of cours I'm not very interested in dimension $0$, but what about dimensions $2,3$ or $4$ for instance? Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: On $\mathbb{R}^n$, any endomorphism has characteristic polynomial of degree $n$. Hence, if $n$ is odd, it must have a zero, and the endomorphism has an eigenvalue. If $n$ is even, there exists examples without eigenvalue. Note that it's not at all what you noticed with $\mathbb{C}$: every endomorphism of a finite dimensional complex linear space does have an eigenvalue because $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically close

Comment: You are right on the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{C}$. As for he degree of the characteritic polynomial I agree, I had not thought that the parity of $n$ would be the key here so thank you!

Comment: This is a direct application of the intermediate value Theorem!

Comment: Really @Didier ? This I don't see why

Comment: A polynomial is a continuous function, and if it is of odd degree, its limits at $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ are infinite of opposite sign, hence it takes negative and positive values: by the IVT, it has to vanish somewhere.

Comment: Oh! Okey thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\dim V$ is odd, and $f\colon V\longrightarrow V$ is an endomorphism, then $f$ has some eigenvalue, since the characteristic polynomial of $f$ has odd degree, and therefore it has a real root.

But if $\dim V$ is even, if you take $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $2k=\dim V$, and if $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_{2k}\}$ is a basis of $V$, then the endomorphism $f\colon V\longrightarrow V$ such that

- $f(e_1)=-e_2$;
- $f(e_2)=e_1$;
- $f(e_3)=-e_4$;
- $f(e_4)=e_3$;
- $\vdots$
- $f(e_{2k-1})=-e_{2k}$;
- $f(e_{2k})=e_{2k-1}$

has no real eigenvector.

Comment: Indeed the parity of the dimension of $V$ influences the existence of eigenvalues or not, thank you for the details !

Comment: I'm glad I could help.